# Is it legal for an apartment complex to have me sign a lease and never discuss the fact they do quarterly inspections?

Tags: residential-lease, texas

So I just moved in to an apartment complex, I have historically always rented from private persons and they usually have been houses, but I was new to the Austin, TX area and needed to get my family established.

So we just signed a lease with them 3 weeks ago and to my surprise I get a notice about tomorrow we are doing quarterly inspections. I felt like I was in a movie about guards tossing the cells.

There was no discussion about this, during the signing of the lease and if they snuck it in the lease I would be surprised because I did read through the lease.

I do not feel comfortable about somebody coming to my home to do an "inspection". What is this all about as I am new to this state? Honestly, unless they got a warrant I don't want anybody walking in my home. What is a general rule of thumb here, since my understanding is my relationship begins and ends with this document called a lease. If its not in there, I don't have to oblige.

This is the response I got from management:

> The purpose of quarterly inspections is to show that we are
>   maintaining standard upkeep of your home. It is industry standard so
>   as to ensure (and to show record of) the proper condition, of your
>   HVAC unit, smoke detectors, water heater, balcony and fire
>   extinguisher. The inspection should take no longer than a couple of
>   minutes. We upload and keep an electronic record that all units were
>   inspected during each quarterly inspection. I have attached a
>   preventative maintenance form so you can better understand what we are
>   inspecting (this is the form we use during our inspections). I hope
>   this sheds some light on this process.

Comment: We would need to see the lease.  I would expect there to be wording about Landlord may visit the premises with 24 hours notice (or similar) or in case of an emergency.

Comment: @MartinBonner Texas law is also relevant, of course.  Many if not most US states have a landlord-tenant law that places limits on lease provisions; these often have stronger protections for residential tenants.  But those protections vary widely depending on the state and, sometimes, the municipality.

Comment: It appears that Texas law is silent on the matter, so the lease controls, and that Texas courts have held that a landlord cannot enter without a tenant's consent (presumably except in cases of emergency).  If there's nothing in the lease (including terms incorporated by reference to another document, for example house rules or the like) then probably you haven't consented to quarterly inspections and may be able to withhold consent. You should probably talk to a lawyer before doing that, or at least to a tenants' rights group.

Comment: @MartinBonner, I haven't had a chance to take a look at the details of the lease this morning, but I am guessing there is something about 24 hour notice and that they have a key. In which case, a tenant like myself assumes that this is just for when we need a repair not for them to come up with their own policies of quarterly, weekly, daily, hourly inspections. Where is the check and balance there?

Comment: @phoog, I added the response from management.

Comment: Hourly inspections would be a violation of the implied covenant giving you the right to "quiet enjoyment" of your property.  Annual inspections are not (the house I rent out is required *by law* to have an annual inspection of the gas system, and we also need to service the ventilation system annually).  My guess is that quarterly inspections are going to be OK too.

Comment: "industry standard": I've never rented a residence in Texas, but it has certainly not been the policy in any place I've rented in New York, Pennsylvania, Virginia, Indiana, or Connecticut.  Their explanation seems reasonable enough to please a court, however.  If I were you I might try to get them to agree to perform the inspections only in my presence.

Comment: Maybe the lease doesn't mention inspections specifically, but isn't there a clause where the landlord may enter, giving you notice but not requiring your consent, to do reasonable repairs and maintenance?  I would understand that to require repairs and maintenance that they do proactively, not only at your request.  Then the inspections would be part of maintenance, so they can see what may need repair.  The only remaining question would be whether quarterly inspections are "reasonable" and I doubt that a court would find they are not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Texas, if the lease states that the landlord can inter for some purpose, the landlord can enter for that purpose. I assume there is no statement in the lease. Then the landlord has no right to enter [except in emergencies and for routine inspections or repair](https://www.depts.ttu.edu/sls/forms/Tenants-Rights-Handbook.pdf). This right, however, stems from the courts and not statutes, and you could theoretically sue the landlord to prevent such an inspection (you would need a good attorney, to overcome the presumption that reasonable routine inspections with notice are allowed).

Comment: I have rented apartments and houses in MI, NJ, and MD. In each case there was a provision in the lease for inspection by landlord with reasonable notice (usually 24 hrs). In both NJ and MD the law *required* such inspections at least once a year. with a report to a state agency. If there is a provision for such in your lease, or in TX law you have no choice. If not, you may be able to refuse. But this is not an unusual provision.

Comment: I want to thank all of you. I ended up letting the maintenance guys in. It took less than 5 minutes and they were polite and considerate, but you know I am not one to just give up my rights for convenience so I appreciate the active responses, it was very educational and I now know what questions to ask in a future apartment complex although I think I will go back to renting from private persons and the problems that comes with. I figure they can only afford no more than one attorney, compared to a corporation and the lease is not a manual of a document.